# What is the meaning of x86 instruction "call dword ptr ds:[00923030h]"?

Tags: assembly, x86, addressing-mode

What does the following x86 assembler instruction do?

```
call dword ptr ds:[00923030h]
```

It's an indirect call I suspect, but exactly how does it compute the address to the call?

Answer (score 17):

**[EDIT] Updated**

Whenever you see a memory operand that looks something like `ds:0x00923030`, that's a *segment-relative* addressing mode.  The actual address being referred tp is at linear address 0x00923030 relative to the base address of the `ds` segment register.

Memory segmentation in the x86 architecture is somewhat confusing, and I think [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation) does a good job of explaining it.

Basically, x86 has a number of special *segment* registers: `cs` (*code* segment), `ds` (*data* segment), `es`, `fs`, `gs`, and `ss` (*stack* segment).  Every memory access is associated with a certain segment register.  Normally, you don't specify the segment register, and depending on how the memory is accessed, a default segment register is used.  For example, the `cs` register is used for reading instructions.

Each segment register has a certain *base address* and a *limit*.  The base address determines the physical address that linear address 0x00000000 corresponds to, and the limit determines the maximum allowable linear address for that segment.  For example, if the base address were 0x00040000 and the limit was 0x0000FFFF, then the only valid linear addresses would be 0x00000000 to 0x0000FFFF, and the corresponding physical addresses would be 0x00040000 to 0x0004FFFF.

Thus, the physical address at which the subroutine being called resides is given by the base address stored in the `ds` segment register, plus 0x00923030.  But we're not done yet -- the instruction has the word `ptr` in it.  This adds an extra level of indirection, so the actual target of the subroutine is the address *stored* at the location `ds:0x00923030`.

In AT&T syntax (accepted by the GNU assembler), the instruction would be written as follows:

```
lcall *ds:0x00923030
```

For the full gory details of what the instruction does, see the [80386 reference manual](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/CALL.htm).  This particular variant of the instruction is `"CALL r/m16"` (call near register indirect/memory indirect).

Comment: Not quite, I think, there's an indirection involved. Thus it should be:

The physical address at which the subroutine being called resides is given by the value at the base address stored in the ds segment register plus 0x00923030.

Comment: A segment selector doesn't point to a physical address like you say, but to a linear address. The physical address instead is obtained in the final step, when the logical address has already been resolved to a linear address.

Comment: Yup, segmented -> linear, then virtual -> physical.

Comment: Also, all memory access in x86 is relative to some segment.  `ds:` is the default for data addressing modes other than `ebp` or `esp` as base registers.  This answer also seems to imply that `call ds:1234` would have fewer levels of indirect, i.e. it might do EIP=1234 instead of loading a new EIP value from the memory address `ds:1234`.  But that makes no sense; the `ds:` in `ds:1234` already means it's a (data) memory source operand.

Comment: And no, this is `call r/m32`, not `16`.  *d*word is 32 bits, word is 16.  Most of these mistakes are minor and there is a somewhat good answer buried under them, but the answer on the linked duplicate is pretty good.

Answer (score 10):

This specific opcode makes a call through the virtual address (32bit here) residing at the location pointed to by the logical address `ds:[00923030h]`.
A logical address is made of two components:

1. A 16 bit segment selector, ds in this case, which is basically an index into the (global / local) descriptor table managed by the operating system. Such a selector also holds access rights information for the given segment which is checked upon access (current privilege level, [CPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(computer_security)))
2. A 32bit offset
   The final address is then computed as follows: base address fetched from selector + offset

Please note that the above calculation denotes a linear address, *not* a physical one (see intel manuals [volume 3a](http://www.intel.com/design/processor/manuals/253668.pdf), figure 2.2), which is then translated via the standard mechanism for 4KB paging, i.e. the address consists of an index to page directory, page table and an offset into the selected page. Keep in mind though, that all main stream operating system use the so called flat memory modell, which means that all segment selectors point to address 0x00000000 with the limit set to 0xFFFFFFFF, which is the reason why you can cast between all segments and ultimately leads to (easy) exploitation  of buffer overflows.

The assembler instruction you have given, is very likely to be a call through the Import Address Table (see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) great article for more details) of an executable file, i.e. it's pretty unlikely that this is an ordinal subroutine call.
Code like this is emitted by compilers because the final virtual address of an imported function from an external dll cannot be known in general at compile time (due to rebasing of dlls). By using such a calling construct, the OS loader can insert the correct virtual address at the address pointer to by the logical address and the compiler doesn't need to care which address the final function has anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`call dword ptr ds:[00923030h]`, meaning `call` something value in pointer `00923939h` in `data segment`

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, it takes the value of the DS register (and shifts it left 4 bits), adds to that the immediate value given, fetches a dword value from the resulting memory location, which becomes the address to call. (EDIT: this holds true for 16-bit real mode, for protected mode see the other answers.)

Comment: this is wrong, the offset is not added to the value of the ds register. This is actually a logical address.

Comment: It's not real mode because it's using DWORD operand-size for the new address (and it's not a far call).  In real mode, it would only be a `word ptr` function pointer.